# Correlation functions of composite operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, resource-recommendations, correlation-functions

I am looking for resources, where there are examples of **calculation of correlation functions between composite operators**. This is very basic and natural question, but unfortunately, I don't have any sources..

I am interested in any examples, but if to be concrete, I wanna to understand some basic examples:

1. $\lambda \phi^4$ theory:
   $$
   \langle \phi^2(x) \phi^2(y)\rangle = ?
   $$
   $$
   \langle T_{\mu\nu}(x) T_{\mu\nu}(y)\rangle = ?
   $$
2. $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM:
   $$
   \langle tr(\phi_i \phi_j) tr(\phi_k \phi_l) \rangle = ?
   $$

Comment: The calculation and renormalization of $\langle \phi^2(x) \phi^2(y) \rangle$ in $\phi^4$ theory is treated in detail by both Zinn-Justin's and Amit's textbooks

Comment: @SethWhitsitt did you mean this book?https://www.amazon.com/Field-Theory-Renormalization-Critical-Phenomena/dp/9812561196

Comment: Yes, that's the book. It's a fairly good one for leaning statistical field theory applied to critical phenomena.

Answer (score 2):

There is a short section in the book devoted to the correlation functions of composite operators https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/gaugegravity-duality/16CCA2E431B24AEF1B51B0F9C5BE755E. [image]

However, as far as I understand, there is not a much information about them, because the renormalization is rather complicated, because instead of simply being multplied by some factor, there arise different operators.

Comment: Thank you! Your screenshot is about renormalization of such operators.. Of course, it is related to my question. But my question is very natural in my opinion, so it is strange, that I can't found any references about it..

Comment: There's also book by Collins https://www.amazon.com/Renormalization-Cambridge-Monographs-Mathematical-Physics/dp/0521311772 about renormalization of such operators. But in my opinion, this book is quite old and main example of author $\phi^3_6$ is very unnatural and lead to a lot of confusions.